# Swap column value with the same column of another record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this fairly straightforward table with `ID`, `Position`, `Name` columns.

```
ID  Position  Name
1   1         RecordX
2   3         RecordY
3   2         RecordZ
```

The `Position` column serves as an index for displaying the records in a user defined order, it should be unique, can not be lower than 1 and not be higher than the number of records in the table, in this case 3. The column doesn't enforce uniqueness so temporarily there can be 2 records with the same `Position`, but eventually no two records should have the same position for the correct working of the program.
Currently, in order to swap the position of two records I need to do 3 queries, namely:

1. find the other record's `ID`
2. update the current record's `Position` to match the other record's `Position`
3. update the other record's `Position` by it's previously found `ID` (Since momentarily there will be two records with the same `Position`, updating by `Position` is not possible.

I feel there should be a way to do this with less rounds to the database, and thus with less than 3 queries. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Can you give a data example?  Are you saying that you'll have a table such as (id, new_position), and so doing many swaps in a single query?  Or will you be just be doing one swap operation at a time?

Comment: @Dems one swap operation at a time. So for example record 1 will get position 2, and then record 3 should get position 1.

Comment: Here's how I'd do it in a more capable SQL product: pass in a table-valued parameter with the pairs of IDs to swap, then use `MERGE` which joins to the table containing the positions. Instead of a table parameter, you could use a permanent 'staging' base table that gets cleared down before use. Instead of `MERGE` you could use an `UPDATE` statement. If using a staging base table, you could create a `VIEW` to simplify the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @onedaywhen : Even with a table of swap parameters, the fact that the order of the swaps matters will make a mess for you.  How would you resolve the following on the sample data?  parms(old_pos, new_pos) = {(1,2), (2,3)}?  [Pos1 moves to Pos2, which means that the second item in the table means to work on what is CURRENTLY Pos1].  Either you recursively reformulate the parameters, or you process them sequentially.

Comment: @Dems: I was assuming they'd "just be doing one swap operation at a time".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single "swap" operation...

SWAP(@old_pos, @new_pos)

```
UPDATE
  my_table
SET
  position = CASE WHEN position = @old_pos THEN @new_pos ELSE @old_pos END
WHERE
  position IN (@old_pos, @new_pos)
```

This doesn't easily expand to a table of swap-operations though.  This is because it will try to do all the swaps at once, when in fact the swaps must happen in a specific order...

Also, if you want to do SWAP(@id, @new_pos) you need to either do a sub-query or self join on the table you are updating.  MySQL doesn't like that, and although there are ways around the limitation, it makes things get a bit messy...

```
UPDATE
  my_table
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT position AS old_pos, @new_pos AS new_pos FROM (SELECT position FROM my_table WHERE id = @id)) AS params
    ON my_table.position IN (params.old_pos, params.new_pos)
SET
  myTable.position = CASE WHEN position = old_pos THEN new_pos ELSE old_pos END
```

(I *think* that will work)

**NOTE:**

Both of these assume that BOTH @old_pos and @new_pos, or @id and @new_pos are found, it doesn't check, and *will* make a mess if they don't exist.

This can be resolved by putting it in a transaction, and rolling back if ROW_COUNT() shows that only 1 record is updated.

Comment: I do one swap operation at a time, so a "table of swap operations" seems not needed. Do I understand correctly that your query will be suitable then? It look viable to me. :)

Comment: For a single swap, the fist code example should be fine for you.

Comment: The second one seems nicer suited because it uses the ID, but mysql reports incorrect syntax at 'FROM my_table'. Is it correct syntax to use FROM in an UPDATE query?

Comment: You're right.  It should be UPDATE <query> SET <fields>.  I'll update, but I don't have access to MySQL, you may have to ply a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @new_pos_for_id_1:=3, @new_pos_for_id_3:=1;
UPDATE my_table
    JOIN (
        SELECT 1 as id, @new_pos_for_id_1 as new_position
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3 as id, @new_pos_for_id_3 as new_position) as positions
    USING (id)
SET position = new_position
```

This query can be used to change positions for several rows at a time. I like the @Dems' solution as well.

UPD:

**Explanation**

```
SELECT 1 as id, 3 as new_position
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as id, 1 as new_position
```

is a on-fly constructed table of two columns: `id, new_position` where each id is mapped to some new intended position. THen I just `JOIN` the table with `my_table` on the common `id` field and substitute values in my_table with values from the constructed table.

Comment: I don't understand where in your query I should put my parameters? I have the `ID` of the current record and possibly the intended new `Position`. Can you update your answer?

Comment: @bazzz, i updated the answer in terms of MySQL, but, in practice, I would substitute MySQL variables with named variables from Python (or PHP) MySQL binding.

Comment: +1 for providing this useful answer but in my case I do 1 swap operation at a time and your query seems to rebuild the `Position` list for all records. Your answer would be the right one for a different question. :)

Comment: @bazzz, ok, my solution works for arbitrary changes at a time, but I updated it for swapping two values =)

Comment: @newtover - assumes knowledge the op said he wants to avoid looking up.  Specifically, this requires knowing the IDs of both records being updated, as well as their new positions.  If only half of that information is known (such as `id, new_position` for just one record), how would you go about that?

Comment: @Dems, nice point, but you have already answered the question, so I will better leave my answer as it is =)

Comment: @newtover I have to agree with Dems that your approach is less suitable for my case as I do not know the ID of the "other" record ahead.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work for any DBMS.

```
-- create some data
DROP TABLE ztable CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE ztable
    ( id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , val INTEGER 
    );      

INSERT INTO ztable(id,val) VALUES (1,1), (2,3), (3,2);
SELECT * FROM ztable;

UPDATE ztable t1
SET val=t2.val
FROM ztable t2
WHERE t1.id IN (2,3)
AND t2.id IN (2,3)
AND t1.id <> t2.id
    ;       
SELECT * FROM ztable;
```

Results:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |   1
  2 |   3
  3 |   2
(3 rows)

UPDATE 2
 id | val 
----+-----
  1 |   1
  2 |   2
  3 |   3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: won't work in MySQL.  It doesn't like the table being referenced twice if it's being updated.  (No self joins, sub-queries, etc, unless you hide it away inside something like `(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM my_table))`

Comment: I stand corrected. The method stays pretty much the same if one hides the self-join behind a subquery or join. IIRC some DBMSs allow USING to specify a subquery for an UPDATE or DELETE.