# Efficient update data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Now I want to create a game's ranking system, Assume for a moment that current ranking as follows：

```
player  rank        
A       : 1 
B       : 2     
C       : 3 
D       : 4 
E       : 5
```

After Player D defeats Player B in a Match，so the rank will change as below:

```
player  rank        
A       :  1    
D       :  2    
B       :  3    
C       :  4    
E       :  5
```

how could I Efficient update data in mysql database?

Comment: why not u have a point system like a football league table? then sort by the sum points

Comment: So you need to swap the ranks if one plays defeats another?

Comment: Can players also drop in rank for any reason? How are you ranking - by number of matches won or some other criteria? I think in general you would be better off calculating rankings as ajreal suggested.

Comment: @HarmeetKaur not just swap the ranks ,we want when player d(rank 4) defeats b(if rand 2),D will rank 2 and then b rank3 、c rank4

Comment: @Revent@ajreal the project is browser-based game on smart phone ,so ranking is simple rands on a defeat b ,so Ranking rose a ,the ranks below b will Rank drop down.

Comment: Please have a look at this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339414/swap-column-value-with-the-same-column-of-another-record)                                    You can swap the ranks using this update query.                           Then you can run a query to decrease the rank for all others by 1 except the ones whose ranks are swapped above.                          update table set rank = (rank - 1) where player != 'A' and player != 'B'

Comment: what will happen if rank 2 defeats rank 4

Comment: what's the logic behind this, why did C become the 4th?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath just simply designd if winner's rank lower than loser,winner's rank replace with loser ,and then all the ranks lower than loser will decrease 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert in stored procedures, but I think if you create a stored procedure with parameters "player1" and "player2" where player1 is the higher ranked player, something like this might work:

```
# Get current player ranks
SET @player1rank = (SELECT `Rank` FROM `RankTable` WHERE `Player` = player1);
SET @player2rank = (SELECT `Rank` FROM `RankTable` WHERE `Player` = player2);
# Drop ranks for player 1 down to player 2
UPDATE `RankTable` SET `Rank` = `Rank`+1 WHERE `Rank` >= @player1rank AND `Rank` < @player2rank;
# Now update player2's rank
UPDATE `RankTable` SET `Rank` = @player1rank WHERE `Player` = player2;
```

As a stored procedure, this would run very fast - an added advantage if your table grows large.

Here is my attempt, which doesn't register in MySQL 4.0 using PhpMyAdmin (can't find version), but it may work on MySQL 5+ and will hopefully get you going in the right direction...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE rerank_players (IN player1 VARCHAR (100), IN player2 VARCHAR (100))
BEGIN
   DECLARE player1rank, player2rank INT;
   SET player1rank = (SELECT Rank FROM RankTable WHERE Player = player1);
   SET player2rank = (SELECT Rank FROM RankTable WHERE Player = player2);
   UPDATE RankTable SET Rank = Rank+1 WHERE Rank >= player1rank AND Rank < player2rank;
   UPDATE RankTable SET Rank = player1rank WHERE Player = player2;
END
$$
```

You will need to adjust the length of the VARCHAR in the parameter declarations to your data length as well as rename tables & fields, etc...

Comment: I'm trying your answer,thanks for your help